# Trouble in redirecting to another page from IE after ajax post (Description Inside)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, internet-explorer

Consider I had 2 html pages,

1. index.html
2. info.html

index.html consists of a sign up form to view the info.html, which saves the details on signup to the server and redirect to info.html page.

It works well on every browser except Internet explorer. But in IE It doesn't redirect. I'm using the following code,

```
function StartService(param) {
var ajaxUrl = "/WebService.asmx/Notify";

    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    crossDomain: true,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    url: ajaxUrl,
    data: param,
    dataType: "json",
    success: successTest,
    error: errorTest
});

function successTest(data) {
    var result = data.d;
    //console.log(result);
    if (result === 'success') {
        setTimeout(function () { window.location.href = 'info.html'; }, 3000);
    } else {
        alert(result);
    }
}

function errorTest(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    console.log(xhr.responseText);
}
```

}

Can someone please help with this.

Comment: What it logs "console.log(result);" ?

Comment: @JitendraPancholi It logs 'success'

Comment: Have you tried using == instead of === ?

Comment: @JitendraPancholi yes, It is not working.

Comment: Any specific version of IE is creating issue?

Comment: @JitendraPancholi I'm not yet figured that, but I'm using IE10

Comment: Do you have any URL of your application, I would like to check it out.

Comment: @JitendraPancholi No:-(

Comment: For a time being, you can host your application on you local machine and share the URL if possible for you. :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the absolute url at the window.location.href statement?

IE could be having problems with that.